# Docker build for Mattermost, /bin/sh dnf not found

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, centos, centos8

I've got a CentOS 8 install, and I'm trying to use a docker container to run Mattermost to set up a local node for my family to use. I've been searching a lot online, but my google-fu appears to be weak as I can't get answers that address my issue.

I've downloaded docker, and docker compose using the following guide, again tailoring it to Centos - https://docs.mattermost.com/install/prod-docker.htm I've successfully run the "Hello World" container.

I'm using this guide and trying to tailor the Mattermost container install - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ma ... ith_Docker

I've edited the ~/mattermost-docker/db/Dockerfile to remove references to apk, and put in yum and then dnf, and tried to execute with SUDO in the script and using SU account to run the script. Latest Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.4-alpine

ENV DEFAULT_TIMEZONE UTC

# Install some packages to use WAL
RUN echo "azure<5.0.0" > pip-constraints.txt
RUN dnf install -y \
      build-base \
      curl \
      libc6-compat \
      libffi-dev \
      linux-headers \
      python-dev \
      py-pip \
      py-cryptography \
      pv \
      libressl-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip --no-cache-dir install -c pip-constraints.txt 'wal-e<1.0.0' envdir \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && dnf clean all

# Add wale script
COPY setup-wale.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

#Healthcheck to make sure container is ready
HEALTHCHECK CMD pg_isready -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB || exit 1

# Add and configure entrypoint and command
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]

VOLUME ["/var/run/postgresql", "/usr/share/postgresql/", "/var/lib/postgresql/data", "/tmp", "/etc/wal-e.d/env"]
```

However it still fails on: `docker-compose build`

Error -

`````
Building db
Step 1/10 : FROM postgres:9.4-alpine
 ---> 4e66908aa630
Step 2/10 : ENV DEFAULT_TIMEZONE UTC
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03d176f9f783
Step 3/10 : RUN echo "azure<5.0.0" > pip-constraints.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35dbc995f705
Step 4/10 : RUN sudo dnf install -y       build-base       curl       libc6-compat       libffi-dev       linux-headers       python-dev       py-pip       py-cryptography       pv       libressl-dev     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip --no-cache-dir install -c pip-constraints.txt 'wal-e<1.0.0' envdir     && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*     && dnf clean all
 ---> Running in 4b89205fdca3
 
/bin/sh: dnf: not found

ERROR:Service 'db' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c sudo dnf install -y       build-base       curl       libc6-compat       libffi-dev       linux-headers       python-dev       py-pip       py-cryptography       pv       libressl-dev     && pip install --upgrade pip     && pip --no-cache-dir install -c pip-constraints.txt 'wal-e<1.0.0' envdir     && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*     && dnf clean all' returned a non-zero code: 127````

Confirmed dnf, and yum are present in /bin and /usr/bin, confirmed /bin/sh -> /bin/bash. I'm not even sure what question I should be asking, so I'd appreciate some assistance in figuring out how I can get this container stood up.

Thanks.
`````

Comment: You use Alpine Linux as the base image. Alpine uses [apk](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) instead of dnf

Comment: The `FROM` image is still Alpine-based, so it's not going to have a package manager besides `apk` in it.  Typically you'd want to run your database and application in separate containers, maybe using Docker Compose for orchestration.

Comment: @David-Maze Thank you.  I am using docker-compose, just learning it though.  Not sure why they've got it set up that way.  It's something I'll look into in the future.

Comment: @andrei-kovrov Ok, I'll figure out what parameters I can use in the FROM line and see if I can't tailor that to CentOS.